# flutter listview with radio not showing in alertDialog

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

This is the code.
code:

```
  class ThemeChangerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> string = ['Light', 'Dark', 'Amoled'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final stateData = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
  final ThemeData state = stateData.getTheme();

  return Theme(
  data: state.copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: state.accentColor),
  child: AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: state.primaryColor,
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      title: Text('Select Theme', style: state.textTheme.body1),
      content: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return RadioListTile(
            value: index,
            groupValue: themes.indexOf(state),
            onChanged: (ind) {
              onThemeChanged(ind, stateData);
            },
            title: Text(
              string[index],
              style: state.textTheme.body2,
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: string.length,
      )),
      );
     }
     }'
```

> errors-The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>
> RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

some times throw this error instead of above `LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.`

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.
If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, you should be able to achieve that effect by just giving the viewport loose constraints, without needing to measure its intrinsic dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

AlertDialog uses an `IntrinsicWidth` widget that doesn't allow `ListView.builder`. You have to give a specific width to your `ListView` Example:

```
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Dialog'),
      content: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
           //Your content here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: this solution also work when you got this error `LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.`

Comment: SizedBox(width: double.maxFinite, child: ...)
works also and might be better since container has a lot of extra bells and whistles you don't need. i'm happy i found a solution, but why does this work? and is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @1housand . `SizedBox` is a better way of doing this. I wasn't as experienced at that time so I used `Container`. I've updated the answer. This works because `ListView` takes as much width as it possibly can and `IntristicWidth`  sizes itself to have the same width as its child. Therefore, you have to constrain the width of the IntristicWidth's child.

Answer (score -1):

Not getting right way to fetch data from api in dialog box instead using Statefulbuilder and also wrapped with Sized Box, But not getting right path its only using index with void function even data will print only with index of int function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).