# (RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions

Tags: flutter, user-interface, singlechildscrollview

I am facing this
Exception :

> FlutterError (RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic
> dimensions. Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require
> instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of
> viewports being lazy. If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the
> viewport in the main axis direction, consider a
> RenderShrinkWrappingViewport render object (ShrinkWrappingViewport
> widget), which achieves that effect without implementing the intrinsic
> dimension API.)

When i add `ProductsWidget` the Exception occurs.

**the code of Products Widget is:**

```
class ProductsWidget extends GetResponsiveView<HomeTabController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 3,
      // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
        children: [
          Row()])}}
```

**the calling code is:**

```
body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      //  flex: 1,
                      child: HomeAppBar()),
                  // listView
                  // i made shrinkWrap=true
                  // neverScroll
                  Flexible(fit: FlexFit.tight, child: ProductsWidget()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
```

Answer (score 10):

Try wrapping your ProductsWidget in a SizedBox and give it a width (width: double.maxFinite,) and potentially height.

I had a similar issue and I found the following post helpful: [flutter listview with radio not showing in alertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891838/flutter-listview-with-radio-not-showing-in-alertdialog)

Answer (score 6):

That is because ListView builds each child lazily. You can use a Column wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView instead of the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `SingleChildScrollView` with `CustomScrollView` like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Expanded Scrollable'),
  ),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        fillOverscroll: true,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Hello ... '),
            Divider(
              height: 2,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(color: Colors.red,), // replace this Container with your listview
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by wrapping with SizedBox and give potential height and width. Then I wrapped the SizedBox with Column.

Answer (score 0):

Convert ListView to List.generate and it will solve the problem.